# RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument, MPLS on mininet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mininet

I am trying to apply MPLS on mininet and I was able to install iproute2, the problem that I have is when I try to use any command in the format

```
ip -f mpls xxx
```

I always get an error.

I was able to inser a route

```
mininet> r1 ip route add 10.0.4.0/24 encap mpls 400 via inet 172.16.1.2
mininet> r1 ip route show
10.0.1.0/24 dev r1-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.1 
10.0.4.0/24  encap mpls  400 via 172.16.1.2 dev r1-eth1 
172.16.1.0/24 dev r1-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.1
```

but I am not able to see it using the correct command for mpls

```
mininet> r1 ip -f mpls route show
mininet>
```

also when I try to do a swap of the labels I get an error

```
mininet> r5 ip -f mpls route add 400 as 405 via inet 172.16.8.2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I solved my problem by changing the value on /proc/sys/net/mpls/platform_labels the value set here will be the highest label value that can be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the value on /proc/sys/net/mpls/platform_labels the value set here will be the highest label value that can be used

But keep in mind that I have to set this value for all the devices on my mininet network as well as loading the mpls module and any parameter

```
* modprobe mpls_router
* modprobe mpls_gso
* modprobe mpls_iptunnel
* sysctl -w net.mpls.platform_labels=1048575
* sysctl -w net.mpls.conf.*-eth#.input=1 #for every interface that speaks mpls
```

I thought that doing it in it kernel will activate it for all, but apparently it has to be done within every device on the network